# make a list of multiple individual dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

Let's say I have a list:

```
l = [1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3]
```

How would I loop through to make a list of multiple individual dictionaries?

```
newl = [{1:7}, {2:4}, {3:2}, {4:1}, {4:3}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be to initialize the dicts within a list comprehension which iterates over both the even and the odd elements:

```
 l = [1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3]

 newl = [{k: v} for k, v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]

 #  [{1: 7}, {2: 4}, {3: 2}, {4: 1}, {4: 3}]
```

If performance counts, please note @Netwave 's comment: here two additional lists are created which can be avoided (see their answer here).

Comment: You are creating 2 intermediate lists here, just for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
>>> [{l[i]:l[i+1]} for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
[{1: 7}, {2: 4}, {3: 2}, {4: 1}, {4: 3}]
```

Comment: IIRC the dict creation part is not to be named _dict comprehension_, it's the way how dicts can be initialized. A dict comprehension should have the same pattern like a LC, e.g. {key: value for key, value in zip(itrblA, itrblB)}

Answer (score 2):

Another efficient way is to use `iter`:

```
>>> l = [1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> [{x:y} for x,y in zip(it, it)]
[{1: 7}, {2: 4}, {3: 2}, {4: 1}, {4: 3}]
```

Or use `itertools.islice` for efficient iteration and no extra memmory overhead:

```
[{k: v} for k, v in zip(islice(l, 0, None, 2), islice(l, 1, None, 2))]
```